# socat device files not removed when interface is closed

Tags: linux, ethernet, socat

I am using `socat` version 1.7.3.2 to create a character device from a VLAN Ethernet device for communication. I create the device using following command:

```
socat INTERFACE:wwan0.vlan_dev1,type=2 PTY,mode=0777,rawer,link="/dev/ser_vlan0" &
```

It creates files as:

```
/dev/ser_vlan0 -> /dev/pts/22
```

Even after the `wwan0` device is removed, the files `/dev/ser_vlan0` and `/dev/pts/22` still exist.

Is there a way to remove these files automatically when `wwan0` no longer exists?

Comment: While `socat` is still running?

Comment: yes, the `socat` is still running but the network device is gone. So can it automatically clear the buffer and delete the device?

Comment: According to documentation, it does, in some cases. So, the `/dev/ser_vlan0` is the actual file and `/dev/pts/22` the symbolic link, right? Is this what that arrow `->` is for in your question?

Comment: The closest thing that looks like the solution you want is [`unlink-close`](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/athena/system/i386_deb50/os-ubuntu-9.04/usr/share/doc/socat/socat.html#OPTION_UNLINK_CLOSE). Can you test it and confirm?

Comment: I tried with `unlink-close` and this doesn't work. The socat keeps the file open for sometime. It is not killed immediately.

Comment: But, it is killed, eventually?

Comment: after sometime. I don't know what is the event that kills it.

Comment: Right. That delay could be due to the `timeout` i.e. `0.5` second. From [OPTIONS](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/athena/system/i386_deb50/os-ubuntu-9.04/usr/share/doc/socat/socat.html#OPTIONS) documentation: **"`-t<timeout>`: When one channel has reached EOF, the write part of the other channel is shut down. Then, socat waits <timeout> [timeval] seconds before terminating. Default is 0.5 seconds. This timeout only applies to addresses where write and read part can be closed independently. When during the timeout interval the read part gives EOF, socat terminates without awaiting the timeout."**

Comment: Can you test it with a smaller `timeout` value?

Comment: Are you saying that `socat` itself was `kill`ed?

Comment: If `socat` terminates on disconnecting device, you can run it in a loop as show in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032549/socat-terminates-after-connection-close

Comment: The option you specified `-t 0` works perfect for me. Please post that as an answer. :)

Comment: Finally! :) Sure. I'm posting that as an answer. I'd suggest that you update your question with your final command for it'll help others in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `socat`'s [OPTIONS](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/athena/system/i386_deb50/os-ubuntu-9.04/usr/share/doc/socat/socat.html#OPTIONS) documentation:

**-t < timeout >:**

> When one channel has reached EOF, the write part of the other channel
>   is shut down. Then, socat waits  seconds before
>   terminating. Default is 0.5 seconds. This timeout only applies to
>   addresses where write and read part can be closed independently. When
>   during the timeout interval the read part gives EOF, socat terminates
>   without awaiting the timeout.

You need to set the `timeout` as `0`.